# How to send checkin via api to swarm

Tags: php, api, foursquare, checkin

Hi how can i send checkin to swarm via swarm api from external php application. Is there a way to send checkin via api calling as like to posting post to facebook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Gokigooooks already said important things. And URL sample:

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/checkins/add?
venueId=IHR8THISVNU& // The venue where the user is checking in
broadcast=public,facebook& // POST TO FACEBOOK
ll=33.7,44.2& // User location
alt=44.038330& // User altitude (option)
oauth_token=(OAUTH_TOKEN)& // User aouth token (need login)
v=20150929 // api version
```

**EDIT**

After checkin, Checkin `id` will be returned. (e.g. `IHR8THISVNU`)

Then you need to access the following URL

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/photos/add?
checkinId =IHR8THISVNU& // the ID of a checkin owned by the user
broadcast=facebook& // POST TO FACEBOOK
public=1& // allows for making the photo public and viewable at the venue (option)
oauth_token=(OAUTH_TOKEN)& // User aouth token (need login)
v=20150929 // api version
```

In addition, the image file data must be posted. The image data is sent as the POST message body on the HTTP request.

ref. [FourSquare Photo upload on checkin with Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13795109/foursquare-photo-upload-on-checkin-with-android)

Comment: I can send checkin without image via foursquare api . I want to send wheckin with photo via foursquare api. How can i make that, i saw "photos/add" api but i don t understand.

Answer (score 1):

As quoted [here](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/2014update), your still gonna be using foursquare API.

First things first, you're gonna need an api key for your application to make requests to foursquare. and Yes, your users can check in from your app.

read more about checking in end point in their documentation [here](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/checkins/add)

good luck